# Passing Some Data Back to the Launcher View Controller

Tags: swift, macos, segue, nsviewcontroller

I'm calling a segue(sheet) from the Main View Controller to open a second view controller.I'm passing some data to the New View Controller by overriding the `prepareforsegue` function

```
override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      if (segue.identifier == "segue") {
            //get a reference to the destination view controller
      let destinationVC:myview = segue.destinationController as! myview
            //set properties on the destination view controller
            destinationVC.fileArray=fileArray

        }
    }
```

Im performing some operation on the second view controller.I need to pass the result of this function to the parent/laucher view controller once the operation is complete/preferably when the new view controller is Close/Disposed.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: in this Scenario you can implement the custom delegate it would be easy for you.

Comment: Look up unwind segue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you will be going back run function with:

```
if let presenter = presentingViewController as? YourFirstController {
    presenter.fileArray = fileArray
}
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```